# Makefile is skipping certain dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So I am writing a makefile that will take some files (*.in) as input to my C++ program and compare their output (results.out) to given correct output (*.out).
Specifically I have files t01.in, t02.in, t03.in, t04.in, and t05.in.
I have verified that $TESTIN = t01.in t02.in t03.in t04.in t05.in.
The problem is that it seems to run the %.in: %.out block only for three of these files, 1,3, and 4. Why is it doing this?

```
OUTPUT = chart
COMPILER = g++
SOURCES = chart.cpp
HEADERS = 
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
TESTIN = tests/*.in


all: $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): $(OBJS)
    $(COMPILER) *.o -o $(OUTPUT)

%.o: %.cpp
    clear
    $(COMPILER) -c $< -o $@


test: $(TESTIN)

%.in: %.out
    ./$(OUTPUT) < $@ > tests/results.out
    printf "\n"
ifeq ($(diff $< tests/results.out), ) 
    printf "\tTest of "$@" succeeded for stdout.\n"
else
    printf "\tTest of "$@" FAILED for stdout!\n"
endif
```

Additionally, if there is a better way of accomplishing what I am trying to do, or any other improvements I could make to this makefile (as I am rather new at this), suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: If I add a second dependency to the block (%.in: %.out %.err), it runs the block for all five files. Still no idea why it works this way but not the way before.

Comment: This rule doesn't make a lot of sense.  `%.in: %.out` means "a rule for **creating** `foo.in` from `foo.out`".  But it sounds like you have the `.in` files *a priori*?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes I have the .in files already. How should this be restated then so that the `%.in: %.out` block runs for each file in `$(TESTIN)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** I don't see how `TESTIN` can be correct. This line:

```
TESTIN = tests/*.in
```

is not a valid wildcard statement in Make; it should give the variable `TESTIN` the value `tests/*.in`. But let's suppose it has the value `t01.in t02.in t03.in t04.in t05.in` or `tests/t01.in tests/t02.in tests/t03.in tests/t04.in tests/t05.in`, or wherever these files actually are.

**Second,** as @OliCharlesworth points out, this rule:

```
%.in: %.out
    ...
```

is a rule for building *.in files, which is not what you intend. As for why it runs some tests and not others, **here is my theory**:

The timestamp of `t01.out` is later than that of `t01.in`, so Make decides that it must "rebuild" `t01.in`; likewise `t03.in` and `t04.in`. But the timestamp of `t02.out` is earlier than that of `t02.in`, so Make does not attempt to "rebuild" `t02.in`; likewise `t05.in`. The timestamps of `t02.err` and `t05.err` are later than those of `t02.in` and `t05.in`, respectively, so when you add the `%.err` prerequisite, Make runs all tests. You can test this theory by checking the timestamps and experimenting with `touch`.

Anyway, let's rewrite it. We need a new target for a new rule:

```
TESTS := $(patsubst %.in,test_%,$(TESTIN)) # test_t01 test_t02 ...

.PHONY: $(TESTS) # because there will be no files called test_t01, test_t02,...

$(TESTS): test_%: %.in %.out
    ./$(OUTPUT) < $< > tests/results.out
```

Now for the conditional. Your attempted conditional is in Make syntax; Make will evaluate it before executing any rule, so `tests/result.out` will not yet exist, and variables like `$<` will not yet be defined. We must put the conditional inside the command, in shell syntax:

```
$(TESTS): test_%: %.in %.out
    ./$(OUTPUT) < $< > tests/results.out
    if diff $*.out tests/results.out >/dev/null; then \
  echo Test of $* succeeded for stdout.; \
  else echo Test of $* FAILED for stdout!; \
  fi
```

(Note that only the first line of the conditional must begin with a TAB.)

Comment: You are correct about `TESTIN` and I've fixed that. Also your timestamp theory seems correct. I'm going to try to understand your rewrite now. Thank you.

Comment: You should probably also `exit $$?` in the `else` branch so that Make is made aware of the `diff` failure. Better yet, just skip the conditional and simply run `diff` - the `echo` just restates information which has already been printed, and so doesn't really help a knowledgeable user.

Comment: @tripleee: Did you mean to address your comment to the OP?

Comment: I suppose primarily yes, but I guess your answer could also benefit from this improvement.

Comment: @tripleee: Since the OP asked for "any other improvements", I have to agree that *appending* that variation would be good-- if the answer weren't getting long already. But to offer that variation *instead* of this answer would not be an improvement; it would alter the behavior of the makefile in ways the OP didn't ask for.

Comment: That's why I offered it as a comment to this answer, rather than post another answer similar to yours. I'm not sure if we are disagreeing on anything?

Comment: @tripleee I see your point of removing the `echo` altogether, but I'm trying to get as clean an output as possible (running `make -s test`). If `result.out` and `t0*.out` are drastically different, I don't want the terminal flooding with text: I'll just visually compare the files.

Comment: `diff -q` does that specifically.

Comment: @Beta Could you explain to me this line: `$(TESTS): test_%: %.in %.out`. What is the purpose of the second colon? Thanks.

Comment: @mapierce271: It could just as well be `test_%: %.in %.out`. I used a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern), which is pretty much the same but restricted to a list of targets (in this case `TESTS`).

Comment: `TESTIN = tests/*.in` is legal make as long as you only expect to use TESTIN in a target, prerequisite or rule body (and account for the fact that your expansion doesn't happen until you do use it).